# Why do I have to initialize my UIImageView again?

Tags: ios, swift, null, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an image that I need to change the height for iPhone 6 and taller. I have autolayout settings that would have everything just right for smaller sizes. I connected the `UIImageView` as an outlet and when I try to access the `imageview's` `image` property in `viewDidLoad` I'm accessing a null pointer. If I go through the whole process of creating it programmatically than I have two images on top of each other. I was wondering if there is a fix to this?

Comment: You could connect the height constraints of the UIImageView as an outlet, then just update the constant value of that constraint?

Comment: I'm updating the constant but the placement doesn't seem to be changing. When I output the value of it to the console, it shows the constant's new changed value though

Comment: once updating the constraint, did you call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`